# How do I do indexOfObject or a proper containsObject

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

With an array: How do I do `indexOfObject` or a proper `containsObject`?

I mean I know I could just bridge the Array to `NSArray` and do it there ^^
But there must be a 'native' way of doing this

P.S. for the `containsObject` I guess I could filter the array too but for *indexOf*?

Comment: yes except it is vice-versa max ;) this one came before AND has more info

Comment: you're right sorry I got my copy paste the wrong way round :-( Now updated!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use the built-in `find`, and thus avoid bridging to Objective-C — but only if your element type is [Equatable](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Equatable.html). (If it isn't Equatable, you can make it so with a comparison function and an extension.)

Example:

```
func == (lhs:Piece,rhs:Piece) -> Bool {
    return lhs.val == rhs.val
}

class Piece:Equatable,Printable {
    var val : Int
    var description : String { return String(val) }
    init (_ v:Int) {
        val = v
    }
}
```

Now you can call `find(arr,p)` where `arr` is an `Array<Piece>` and `p` is a `Piece`.

Once you have this, you can develop utilities based on it. For example, here's a global function to remove an object from an array without bridging to Objective-C:

```
func removeObject<T:Equatable>(inout arr:Array<T>, object:T) -> T? {
    if let found = find(arr,object) {
        return arr.removeAtIndex(found)
    }
    return nil
}
```

And test it like this:

```
var arr = [Piece(1), Piece(2), Piece(3)]
removeObject(&arr,Piece(2))
println(arr)
```

---

You can do this for NSObject subclasses too. Example:

```
func == (v1:UIView, v2:UIView) -> Bool {
    return v1.isEqual(v2)
}
extension UIView : Equatable {}
```

Now you can call `find` on an Array of UIView. It's sort of a pain in the butt, though, having to do this for every single class where you want to be able to use `find` on an Array of that class. I have filed an enhancement request with Apple requesting that all NSObject subclasses be considered Equatable and that `==` should fall back on `isEqual:` *automatically*.

**EDIT** Starting in Seed 3, this *is* automatic for UIView and other NSObject classes. So `find` now just works for them.

**EDIT 2** Starting in Swift 2.0, `indexOf` will exist as a method:

```
let s = ["Manny", "Moe", "Jack"]
let ix = s.indexOf("Moe") // 1
```

Alternatively, it takes a function that returns Bool:

```
let ix2 = s.indexOf {$0.hasPrefix("J")} // 2
```

Again, this works only on collections of Equatable, since obviously you cannot locate a needle in a haystack unless you have a way of identifying a needle when you come to it.

**EDIT 3** Swift 2.0 also introduces protocol extensions. This means I can rewrite my global function `removeObject` as a method!

For example:

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollectionType where Generator.Element : Equatable {
    mutating func removeObject(object:Self.Generator.Element) {
        if let found = self.indexOf(object) {
            self.removeAtIndex(found)
        }
    }
}
```

Since Array adopts RangeReplaceableCollectionType, now I can write code like this:

```
var arr = [Piece(1), Piece(2), Piece(3)]
arr.removeObject(Piece(2))
```

Oh, happy day!

Comment: on which scope do i declare the equatable function?

Comment: Sometime around Swift 3 or 4, `indexOf()` became `index(of:)`.

Answer (score 9):

Its actually able to be done in Swift. To get the index use `find(YourArray, ObjectToFind)`

Comment: Unfortunately there are many common situations in which this will not work.

Comment: Like whenever ObjectToFind is not an Equatable. However, things are much better now than they were when I said that way back in June!

Answer (score 4):

As I was told, this isn't available yet / I have to bridge it to NSArray

I don't like this and it feels dirty so I went and did this in an extension. that way it hides the usage of NSArray and allows apple to provide it later

```
import Foundation

extension Array {
    func contains(object:AnyObject!) -> Bool {
        if(self.isEmpty) {
            return false
        }
        let array: NSArray = self.bridgeToObjectiveC();

        return array.containsObject(object)
    }

    func indexOf(object:AnyObject!) -> Int? {
        var index = NSNotFound
        if(!self.isEmpty) {
            let array: NSArray = self.bridgeToObjectiveC();
            index = array.indexOfObject(object)
        }
        if(index == NSNotFound) {
            return Optional.None;
        }
        return index
    }

    //#pragma mark KVC

    func getKeyPath(keyPath: String!) -> AnyObject! {
        return self.bridgeToObjectiveC().valueForKeyPath(keyPath);
    }
}
```

https://gist.github.com/Daij-Djan/9d1c4b1233b4017f3b67

Comment: FYI, remove the # in front of the object. per apple's standards the first parameter should be self described using the function/method call.

Comment: There was one more thing I caught.  func contains(object: AnyObject) -> Bool? ... because Obj-c bridges return optionals, you'll want to explicitly state this by adding the ?

Comment: in this case it will be either, but if you run the code and read the method... you still have to unwrap the optional unfortunately.... The actual return value is an optional no matter what.

Comment: Nonono, all because you say you're going to return a Bool doesn't make it a Bool. Go ahead and run the code. Breakpoint at the return call and you'll see that even though swift says it's valid, it's an optional. Trust me, it's annoying.

Comment: I just ran the code, I can paste a screen shot if you'd like?

Comment: I just posted above, if you don't check this you're going to run into unwanted bugs where if statements will pass where they shouldn't because the 'optional' exists and can be unwrapped. I was just trying to save you guys some headaches, but ok XD. You'll learn the hardway unless they update this issue.

Comment: *sigh*, you don't make it an optional. It's returned as an optional. Ontop of this, the literal return definition from array.containsObject is a Bool?. You can view this for yourself by holding the option key down and clicking the method. At this point though, I'm assuming you're not really checking and just arguing. So yea, you've been warned. I've posted images above showing the returned results of the same method above. There's the example. Read the type that Xcode notes as the returned value

Comment: and as you do, I also assume. and I assume you are just saying stuff... I am in the habit of checking stuff and I tell you its a bool ;) [oh and please provide an SSCCE]

Answer (score 2):

Apple provide an example of exactly this in the [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-XID_275) book. Specifically, see the section on Type Constraints in Action (*p621 in the iBook*).

```
func findIndex<T: Equatable>(array: [T], valueToFind: T) -> Int? {
    for (index, value) in enumerate(array) {
        if value == valueToFind {
            return index
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Everything depends upon your type implementing [Equatable](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Equatable.html).

The Swift Programming Language covers that and explains how to implement that protocol:

> “The Swift standard library defines a protocol called Equatable, which
>   requires any conforming type to implement the equal to operator (==)
>   and the not equal to operator (!=) to compare any two values of that
>   type. ”

[NSHipster](http://nshipster.com) has a couple of relevant posts on this subject:

[Swift Default Protocol Implementations](http://nshipster.com/swift-default-protocol-implementations/)
[Swift Comparison Protocols](http://nshipster.com/swift-comparison-protocols/)

I also found this answer very useful in implementing Equatable:

[How do I implement Swift's Comparable protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24334684/how-do-i-implement-swifts-comparable-protocol)

Alhough it mentions Comparable, Equatable is a subset and the explanation is good.

Excerpts above from: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/gb/jEUH0.l

Comment: some of it, but given Apple's Swift book covers exactly this, would it not be better to include that sample code? Also referencing their explanation? Matt's answer is good but it wasn't helpful to me personally. It only made sense after I had read the Swift guide and other sources; hence my answer.

Answer (score 2):

One other option is to use filter:

```
haystack.filter({$0 == needle}).count > 0
```

This checks to see if array haystack contains object needle.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. That's why `NSArray` is still there. However, the Apple documentation reads as follows about `String` and `NSString`:

> Swift’s String type is bridged seamlessly to Foundation’s NSString
>   class. If you are working with the Foundation framework in Cocoa or
>   Cocoa Touch, the entire NSString API is available to call on any
>   String value you create, in addition to the String features described
>   in this chapter. You can also use a String value with any API that
>   requires an NSString instance.

Following that approach, the `NSArray` API *should* be available on `Array`, but it isn't because the native Swift `Array` is a primitive (most likely a struct or similar), so you have to *"convert"* it to an `NSArray`.

Comment: I said above I could bridge it . I didn't want to believe it :D but I guess I do now :D

Answer (score 1):

It appears that not all of the toll-free bridging from NS/CF space is in place. However, if you declare your array as an NSArray, it works fine:

```
let     fruits: NSArray = [ "apple", "orange", "tomato (really?)" ]
let     index = fruits.indexOfObject("orange")

println("Index of Orange: \(index)")
```

Comment: I said above I could bridge it . I didn't want to believe it :D

Answer (score -2):

If your array elements are objects and you want to find an identical object in that array, you can use this function:

```
func findObject<C: CollectionType where C.Generator.Element: AnyObject>(domain: C, value: C.Generator.Element) -> Int? {
    for (index, element) in enumerate(domain) {
        if element === value {
            return index
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: there is a function called  "indexOfObjectIdenticalTo" of array to get the index for your element
like
 indexOfSelectedObject = arrSelectedIndex.indexOfObjectIdenticalTo(indexPath.row)