# How to remove an element from an array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

How can I unset/remove an element from an array in Apple's new language Swift?

Here's some code:

```
let animals = ["cats", "dogs", "chimps", "moose"]
```

How could the element `animals[2]` be removed from the array?

Answer (score 417, accepted):

The `let` keyword is for declaring constants that can't be changed. If you want to modify a variable you should use `var` instead, e.g:

```
var animals = ["cats", "dogs", "chimps", "moose"]

animals.remove(at: 2)  //["cats", "dogs", "moose"]
```

A non-mutating alternative that will keep the original collection unchanged is to use `filter` to create a new collection without the elements you want removed, e.g:

```
let pets = animals.filter { $0 != "chimps" }
```

Comment: FYI: `remove` returns the removed element: `let animal = animals.remove(at: 2)`

Comment: can we filter only based on index ??

Comment: @shaqirsaiyed You can filter on any predicate you can think up. e.g. you could filter out all animals that end in an "s".

Comment: add animals = pets

Comment: remove(at:) gets me a single item in swift 5 

Answer (score 289):

Given

```swift
var animals = ["cats", "dogs", "chimps", "moose"]
```

### Remove first element

```swift
animals.removeFirst() // "cats"
print(animals)        // ["dogs", "chimps", "moose"]
```

### Remove last element

```swift
animals.removeLast() // "moose"
print(animals)       // ["cats", "dogs", "chimps"]
```

### Remove element at index

```swift
animals.remove(at: 2) // "chimps"
print(animals)           // ["cats", "dogs", "moose"]
```

### Remove element of unknown index

For only one element

```
if let index = animals.firstIndex(of: "chimps") {
    animals.remove(at: index)
}
print(animals) // ["cats", "dogs", "moose"]
```

For multiple elements

```swift
var animals = ["cats", "dogs", "chimps", "moose", "chimps"]

animals = animals.filter(){$0 != "chimps"}
print(animals) // ["cats", "dogs", "moose"]
```

### Notes

- The above methods modify the array in place (except for `filter`) and return the element that was removed.
- [Swift Guide to Map Filter Reduce](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-guide-to-map-filter-reduce/)
- If you don't want to modify the original array, you can use `dropFirst` or `dropLast` to create a new array.

*Updated to Swift 5.2*

Comment: Thanks for these examples, in you *Remove element of unknown index* > *for multiple elements*, what closure would you write to remove `chimps && moose` for instance? I am looking for something different than `{$0 != "chimps" && $0 != "moose"}`

Comment: why bother getting the index just to pass it in?
animals.removeAll{ $0 == "chimps" }

Answer (score 209):

The above answers seem to presume that you know the index of the element that you want to delete.

Often you know the *reference* to the object you want to delete in the array. (You iterated through your array and have found it, e.g.) In such cases it might be easier to work directly with the object reference without also having to pass its index everywhere. Hence, I suggest this solution. It uses the [identity operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24002849/5175709) `!==`, which you use to test whether two object references both refer to the same object instance.

```
func delete(element: String) {
    list = list.filter { $0 != element }
}
```

Of course this doesn't just work for `String`s.

Comment: Should be `list = list.filter({ $0 != element })`

Comment: Not if you want to check with the identity operator.

Comment: `array.indexOf({ $0 == obj })`

Comment: Note if other objects reference `list` this deletion won't update the other array references since you're assigning a new array to `list`. Just a subtle implication if you delete from arrays with this approach.

Comment: @Crashalot "if other objects reference list this deletion won't update the other array references..." Is this because arrays in Swift are structs, am I correct?

Comment: Functional programming paradigm relies on immutable objects. I.e., you don't change them. Instead, you create a new object. This is what delete, map, reduce, etc. does. list will be a newly created object. In the above code snippet I'm assigning back to list a newly created object. That works for me, because I design my code in a way that follows functional programming.

Comment: This will remove every matching element not just a single one.  Let theArray = ["A", "B", "C", "A"]    let newArray = theArray.filter({$0 != "A"})  results in newArray == ["B", "C"]

Comment: If you want to get index of all matching element let filteredIndices = items.enumerated().filter{ "YoutElement" == $0.element }.map{ $0.offset }

Comment: don't need to surround your {} with ()

Answer (score 70):

**Swift 5:**
Here is a cool and easy extension to remove elements in an array, without filtering:

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    
    // Remove first collection element that is equal to the given `object`:
    mutating func remove(object: Element) {
        guard let index = firstIndex(of: object) else {return}
        remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
var myArray = ["cat", "barbecue", "pancake", "frog"]
let objectToRemove = "cat"

myArray.remove(object: objectToRemove) // ["barbecue", "pancake", "frog"]
```

Also works with other types, such as `Int` since `Element` is a generic type:

```
var myArray = [4, 8, 17, 6, 2]
let objectToRemove = 17

myArray.remove(object: objectToRemove) // [4, 8, 6, 2]
```

Comment: Interesting this Array where Element: Equatable part

Comment: Brilliant. Though it doesn't work if you start with a list of Protocols, as — Protocol type cannot conform to 'Equatable' because only concrete types can conform to protocols :-(

Comment: I like this solution because it covers removal of elements that belong to an array of struct

Comment: I was searching for Objective-C equivalent remove function. This answer best fit for that. Thank you.

Answer (score 28):

As of Xcode 10+, and according to the [WWDC 2018 session 223, "Embracing Algorithms,"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/223) a good method going forward will be `mutating func removeAll(where predicate: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows`

Apple's example:

```
var phrase = "The rain in Spain stays mainly in the plain."
let vowels: Set<Character> = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

phrase.removeAll(where: { vowels.contains($0) })
// phrase == "Th rn n Spn stys mnly n th pln."
```

see [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994751-removeall)

So in the OP's example, removing animals[2], "chimps":

```
var animals = ["cats", "dogs", "chimps", "moose"]
animals.removeAll(where: { $0 == "chimps" } )
// or animals.removeAll { $0 == "chimps" }
```

This method may be preferred because it scales well (linear vs quadratic), is readable and clean.  Keep in mind that it only works in Xcode 10+, and as of writing this is in Beta.

Comment: removeAll(where:) will be able only in swift 4.2

Comment: `phrase.removeAll(where: vowels.contains)`

Comment: Apple's Documentation link is broken, updated documentation link here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/removeall(where:)-5k61r

Answer (score 25):

If you have array of custom Objects, you can search by specific property like this:

```
if let index = doctorsInArea.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == doctor.id}){
    doctorsInArea.remove(at: index)
}
```

or if you want to search by name for example

```
if let index = doctorsInArea.firstIndex(where: {$0.name == doctor.name}){
    doctorsInArea.remove(at: index)
}
```

Answer (score 25):

For Swift4:

```
list = list.filter{$0 != "your Value"}
```

Comment: This will remove every matching element not just a single one. Let theArray = ["A", "B", "C", "A"] let newArray = theArray.filter({$0 != "A"}) results in newArray == ["B", "C"]

Answer (score 20):

If you don't know the index of the element that you want to remove, and the element is conform the Equatable protocol, you can do:

```
animals.remove(at: animals.firstIndex(of: "dogs")!)
```

See Equatable protocol answer:[How do I do indexOfObject or a proper containsObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010700/how-do-i-do-indexofobject-or-a-proper-containsobject)

Answer (score 20):

You could do that. First make sure `Dog` really exists in the array, then remove it. Add the `for` statement if you believe `Dog` may happens more than once on your array.

```
var animals = ["Dog", "Cat", "Mouse", "Dog"]
let animalToRemove = "Dog"

for object in animals {
    if object == animalToRemove {
        animals.remove(at: animals.firstIndex(of: animalToRemove)!)
    }
}
```

If you are sure `Dog` exits in the array and happened only once just do that:

```
animals.remove(at: animals.firstIndex(of: animalToRemove)!)
```

**If you have both, strings and numbers**

```
var array = [12, 23, "Dog", 78, 23]
let numberToRemove = 23
let animalToRemove = "Dog"

for object in array {

    if object is Int {
        // this will deal with integer. You can change to Float, Bool, etc...
        if object == numberToRemove {
        array.remove(at: array.firstIndex(of: numberToRemove)!)
        }
    }
    if object is String {
        // this will deal with strings
        if object == animalToRemove {
        array.remove(at: array.firstIndex(of: animalToRemove)!)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if my array does not contain Strings?

Comment: @apqu did another update ' || object == Int()' and '|| object == String()' are unnecessary

Comment: looping an array goes agains efficiency. check .filter, .compactMap

Answer (score 16):

Few Operation relates to Array in Swift

Create Array

```
var stringArray = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"]
```

Add Object in Array

```
stringArray = stringArray + ["Five"]
```

Get Value from Index object

```
let x = stringArray[1]
```

Append Object

```
stringArray.append("At last position")
```

Insert Object at Index

```
stringArray.insert("Going", at: 1)
```

Remove Object

```
stringArray.remove(at: 3)
```

Concat Object value

```
var string = "Concate Two object of Array \(stringArray[1]) + \(stringArray[2])"
```

Comment: `stringArray += ["Five"]` or even better is `stringArray += CollectionOfOne("Five")`

Answer (score 11):

**Remove elements using indexes array:**

1. Array of Strings and indexes

   ```
   let animals = ["cats", "dogs", "chimps", "moose", "squarrel", "cow"]
   let indexAnimals = [0, 3, 4]
   let arrayRemainingAnimals = animals
       .enumerated()
       .filter { !indexAnimals.contains($0.offset) }
       .map { $0.element }

   print(arrayRemainingAnimals)

   //result - ["dogs", "chimps", "cow"]
   ```
2. Array of Integers and indexes

   ```
   var numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
   let indexesToRemove = [3, 5, 8, 12]

   numbers = numbers
       .enumerated()
       .filter { !indexesToRemove.contains($0.offset) }
       .map { $0.element }

   print(numbers)

   //result - [0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11]
   ```

**Remove elements using element value of another array**

3. Arrays of integers

   ```
   let arrayResult = numbers.filter { element in
       return !indexesToRemove.contains(element)
   }
   print(arrayResult)

   //result - [0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11]
   ```
4. Arrays of strings

   ```
   let arrayLetters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]
   let arrayRemoveLetters = ["a", "e", "g", "h"]
   let arrayRemainingLetters = arrayLetters.filter {
       !arrayRemoveLetters.contains($0)
   }

   print(arrayRemainingLetters)

   //result - ["b", "c", "d", "f", "i"]
   ```

Comment: This is one liner answer and it is much efficient for better coding and fast execution.

Comment: Hi @Krunal - great answer, could you take a look at the following question (releasing images from an image array): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735975/how-to-release-images-from-an-image-array-in-swift

Answer (score 9):

I came up with the following extension that takes care of removing elements from an `Array`, assuming the elements in the `Array` implement `Equatable`:

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
  
  mutating func removeEqualItems(_ item: Element) {
    self = self.filter { (currentItem: Element) -> Bool in
      return currentItem != item
    }
  }

  mutating func removeFirstEqualItem(_ item: Element) {
    guard var currentItem = self.first else { return }
    var index = 0
    while currentItem != item {
      index += 1
      currentItem = self[index]
    }
    self.remove(at: index)
  }
  
}
```

#### Usage:

```
var test1 = [1, 2, 1, 2]
test1.removeEqualItems(2) // [1, 1]

var test2 = [1, 2, 1, 2]
test2.removeFirstEqualItem(2) // [1, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Hi @nburk - great answer, could you take a look at the following question (releasing images from an image array): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735975/how-to-release-images-from-an-image-array-in-swift

Comment: This is cleanest solution.

Comment: If the array does not contains the item, self[index] will fail in removeFirstEqualItem method.

Answer (score 7):

Regarding @Suragch's Alternative to "Remove element of unknown index":

There is a more powerful version of "indexOf(element)" that will match on a predicate instead of the object itself.  It goes by the same name but it called by myObjects.indexOf{$0.property = valueToMatch}.  It returns the index of the first matching item found in myObjects array.

If the element is an object/struct, you may want to remove that element based on a value of one of its properties.  Eg, you have a Car class having car.color property, and you want to remove the "red" car from your carsArray.

```
if let validIndex = (carsArray.indexOf{$0.color == UIColor.redColor()}) {
  carsArray.removeAtIndex(validIndex)
}
```

Foreseeably, you could rework this to remove "all" red cars by embedding the above if statement within a repeat/while loop, and attaching an else block to set a flag to "break" out of the loop.

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 5**

```
guard let index = orders.firstIndex(of: videoID) else { return }
orders.remove(at: index)
```

Answer (score 4):

This should do it (not tested):

```
animals[2...3] = []
```

Edit: and you need to make it a `var`, not a `let`, otherwise it's an immutable constant.

Comment: When using a (sub)range of an existing array to create another array the range needs to have 3 dots. The above should be written as animals[2...3]

Comment: `Array` conforms to `RangeReplaceableCollection` protocol and it provides a method exactly for this purpose `animals.removeSubrange(2...3)`

Comment: Just a note that the code in this answer removes two elements, the ones at the indexes 2 and 3. `2..<3.` can be used if wanting to remove only the element at index 2.

Answer (score 2):

extension to remove String object

```
extension Array {
    mutating func delete(element: String) {
        self = self.filter() { $0 as! String != element }
    }
}
```

Comment: force unwrapping can cause a crash, I think you should  avoid it in this case.

Comment: What's a "mutating" func?

Comment: it used to to tell that this function will change the self(array).

Answer (score 2):

I use this extension, almost same as Varun's, but this one (below) is all-purpose:

```
 extension Array where Element: Equatable  {
        mutating func delete(element: Iterator.Element) {
                self = self.filter{$0 != element }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove elements from an array, use the `remove(at:)`,
 `removeLast()` and `removeAll()`.

```
yourArray = [1,2,3,4]
```

Remove the value at 2 position

```
yourArray.remove(at: 2)
```

Remove the last value from array

```
yourArray.removeLast()
```

Removes all members from the set

```
yourArray.removeAll()
```