# In Swift Array, is there a function that returns the last index based in where clause?

Tags: swift

The function *index* of an Swift array returns the first element based on the condition inside the *where* clause. Is there a way to get the last element with this condition?

For example, I want something like this (I know there is no function called lastIndex. This function or similar is what I'm searching for):

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 6]

let indexOfLastElementEquals3 = array.lastIndex(where: { $0 == 3 })

print(indexOfLastElementEquals3) //5 (Optional)
```

Comment: It was added in Swift 4.2: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0204-add-last-methods.md. You'll probably need the latest developer snapshot.

Comment: **array.index(of: 3, options: .backwards)**

Comment: @Sh_Khan That's `String` only, isn't it?

Comment: @Sh_Khan There's no `index(of:options:)` on any class/struct. Perhaps you are thinking of `StringProtocol range(of:options:)`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31954396/2303865

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`lastIndex(where:)` and related methods were added in Swift 4.2,
see

- [SE-0204 Add last(where:) and lastIndex(where:) Methods](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0204-add-last-methods.md).

In earlier Swift versions you can use `index(where:)` on the reversed
view of the collection:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 6]

if let revIndex = array.reversed().index(where: { $0 % 2 != 0 } ) {
    let indexOfLastOddElement = array.index(before: revIndex.base)
    print(indexOfLastOddElement) // 5
}
```

Or as a single expression:

```
let indexOfLastOddElement =  array.reversed().index(where: { $0 % 2 != 0 } )
    .map { array.index(before: $0.base) }

print(indexOfLastOddElement) // Optional(5)
```

`revIndex.base` returns the position *after* the position of `revIndex`
in the underlying collection, that's why we have to “subtract” one
from the index.

For arrays this can be simplified to

```
    let indexOfLastOddElement = revIndex.base - 1
```

but for collections with non-integer indices (like `String`)
the above `index(before:)` methods is needed.

Comment: @Sulthan: Yes, array indices are Int. For other collections (like String) you need index(before:)

Comment: this targets  odd value suppose he searches for an even , also there is no input , it's for this use case only

Comment: @Sh_Khan: I am sorry, I do not understand  what you mean. Is anything wrong here?

Comment: suppose the search for index of last number 6  according to yours , then we have to change the `$0 % 2 != 0` to `$0 % 2 == 0`

Comment: Another way of doing it would be to reverse the `indices`, e.g `array.indices.reversed().first(where: { array[$0] % 2 != 0 } )`. It means you have to do subscripting in the predicate, but on the other hand you don't have to adjust the returned index afterwards.