# Swift last(:where) element in an array

Tags: swift

For an array:

```
var arr = [3,2,1,2,1,4,5,8,6,7,4,2]
```

I can find the first matching element

```
arr.first(where: {$0 == 2})!
```

But the last

```
arr.last(where: {$0 == 2})
```

Returns:

> cannot call value of non-function type 'Int?'

Why?

Comment: What version of Swift (or Xcode) are you using? `last(where:)` was added in Swift 4.2 (Xcode 10).

Comment: 9.4.1 - So that's it then! Thanks

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50279988/in-swift-array-is-there-a-function-that-returns-the-last-index-based-in-where-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`last(where:)` was added in Swift 4.2 (Xcode 10).

If you need to find the last match using Swift 4.1 or earlier, you can do:

```
let last = arr.reversed().first { $0 == 2 }
```

Comment: And for those worried about the performance of this: worry not, `reversed()` simply makes a wrapper around the source array, and just does some index math (`count - 1 - i`) to access an index `i`. There's no array copying going on.

Comment: @Alexander TIL! Cool.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by rmaddy this method still in beta. If you would like to add this functionality also to Swift 4.1 you can extend `BidirectionalCollection` as follow:

```
extension BidirectionalCollection {
    func last(where predicate: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Element? {
        return try reversed().first(where: predicate)
    }
}
```