# how to delete an element that contains a letter in array using swift

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3, element

I am having trouble trying to figure this topic out. Like the topic, How do I delete an element that contains a letter in Array. This is the code I have so far.

```
let newline = "\n"
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/bin/sh"
    task.arguments = ["-c", "traceroute -nm 18 -q 1 8.8.8.8"]

    let pipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.launch()
    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as! String
    var array = output.components(separatedBy: "  ")
    array = array.filter(){$0 != "m"}



    print(array, newline)
```

I have tried multiple options given by this stack overflow. 
[How to remove an element from an array in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051633/how-to-remove-an-element-from-an-array-in-swift)

I think I have hit a wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
array = array.filter({ !$0.contains("m") })
```