# Swift 3 : Remove value in Array with Unknown index

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to implement a multiple click in my Shinobi DataGrid. I have a grid which have array

```
( ["1", "32", and more] )
```

If I click the grid I put it into new Array `self.arrayNr.append(currNr)`.

But I want to check and remove if `currNr` is already exist in `arrayNr` it is will be remove from the `arrayNr`.

I'm new and using Swift 3. I read some question regarding with my question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051633/how-to-remove-an-element-from-an-array-in-swift) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938948/array-extension-to-remove-object-by-value) but it's not working. I think the Swift 2 is simpler than Swift 3 in handling for `String`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `index(of` to check if the `currNr`exists in your array. (The class must conform to the [`Equatable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable) protocol)

```
var arrayNr = ["1", "32", "100"]
let currNr = "32"
// Check to remove the existing element
if let index = arrayNr.index(of: currNr) {
    arrayNr.remove(at: index)
}
arrayNr.append(currNr)
```

Comment: thanks for advice, but there is no argument with `index(of: )` in here. What should it be?

Comment: Take a look again at my example, you will see it's the index of your *currNr* string.

Comment: `index(of: )` only exists for objects that conform to `Equatable` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable

Comment: Oh i see, i declare the array with [Any],  i change it into [String] . Its work thanks

Answer (score 1):

Say you have an array of string, namely type `[String]`. Now you want to remove a string if it exists. So you simply need to filter the array by this one line of code

```
stringArray= stringArray.filter(){$0 != "theValueThatYouDontWant"}
```

For example, you have array like this and you want to remove "1"

```
let array = ["1", "32"]
```

Simply call

```
array = array.filter(){$0 != "1"}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Long Solution**

`sampleArray` iterates over itself and removes the value you are looking for if it exists before exiting the loop.

```
var sampleArray = ["Hello", "World", "1", "Again", "5"]
let valueToCheck = "World"

for (index, value) in sampleArray.enumerated() {
    if value == valueToCheck && sampleArray.contains(valueToCheck) {
        sampleArray.remove(at: index)
        break
    }
}

print(sampleArray) // Returns ["Hello", "1", "Again", "5"]
```

**Short Solution**

`sampleArray` returns an array of all values that are not equal to the value you are checking.

```
var sampleArray = ["Hello", "World", "1", "Again", "5"]
let valueToCheck = "World"

sampleArray = sampleArray.filter { $0 != valueToCheck }

print(sampleArray) // Returns ["Hello", "1", "Again", "5"]
```