# 2D array remove First not Smooth updating tableview

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I have 2D array `var students = [[Student]]` I need to conform this array  should be keep always 3 in memory so when this array insert new itme then remove from old from top

I have to insert array this way

```
self.students.append(student) //Update students  property
```

and trying with this line but 
 `tableview` not update smoothly when I remove item using this line

`self.students.removeFirst()`

so what How can I remove array item  from top for table view smoothly scrolling

Note array hooked table view

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.students.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return students[section].count
}
```

Update :
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051633/how-to-remove-an-element-from-an-array-in-swift ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove an element from an array in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051633/how-to-remove-an-element-from-an-array-in-swift)

Comment: @Larme tableview not update smoothly when I remove item using `self.students.removeFirst()`

Comment: @DávidPásztor tableview not update smoothly when I remove item using `self.students.removeFirst()`

Comment: @NazmulHasan then why didn't you ask about smooth updating? Without editing your question to reflect your **actual** problem, it is a duplicate.

Comment: Do you also call `tableView.reloadData()` after deleting from its datasource array?

Comment: @DávidPásztor I did  `tableView.reloadData()` after remove self.students.removeFirst()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150731/discussion-between-nazmul-hasan-and-david-pasztor).

Comment: @DávidPásztor I edit my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150742/discussion-between-nazmul-hasan-and-david-pasztor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a fixed upper size, you would be better off not removing items at all.

Use a fixed-size array of three items, some of which could be empty, and a separate `count` and `firstIndex` variables. Effectively, your array becomes a [*Circular Queue*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer):

```
var students : [[Student]] = [[], [], []]
var count = 0;
var firstIndex = 0;
// Adding a new item
students[(firstIndex+count) % students.count] = newItem
if (count != 3) {
    count++
} else {
    firstIndex = (firstIndex+1) % students.count
}
// Iterating the array
for var i in (0..<students.count) {
    let currentStudent = students[(firstIndex+i)%students.count]
    ...
}
```

The number of sections is `count`:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return count
}
```

The only trick is to figure out which index to use for a given index path:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return students[(section + firstRow) % students.count].count
}

let actualIndex = (indexPath.section + firstIndex) % students.count
```

Comment: Thank you so much I am trying with your answer in my project and get back you

Comment: it is working fine but when trying to append  4th item  to the a array then flowing Line `(firstIndex+count) % students.count` give me log `3` is 
`fatal error: Index out of range`

Comment: @NazmulHasan This tells me that `students.count` is above 3, which should never happen, because `students.count` is fixed at 3, and any positive number mod `%` 3 is 0, 1, or 2. `append` should be replaced with the circular addition code above.

Comment: thanks basically it is working fine from 1 to 3 but when adding 4th item to the array then tableView  scrolling not goes down so not showing 4th item on the other hand log see array data updated . you can check my question update section image and sample code  https://github.com/nazmulkp/PagginationSwift3

Comment: please help me  I am  stuck all most 7 days

Comment: @NazmulHasan I thought you wanted to cap the number of elements to three. When you add element four, element one should disappear, right? If you want scrolling to continue fine, you should tell `UITableView` that you are deleting rows in the entire section zero by calling `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`. After that you need to tell `UITableView` that you are inserting a bunch of rows at the third section (section index 2). This way you would be able to avoid reloading the whole table, disrupting the scroll.

Comment: Right !  I wanted to cap the number of elements to three. When you add element four, element one should disappear. but I spend all most 7 days . can not mange this . would help me please how can I do this .

Comment: @NazmulHasan Please try what I described in the comment (delete section zero, then insert section 2).

Comment: Thank you so much! I am trying with your described in the comment  get back you

Comment: Sir I unable to resolve the error `'attempt to delete row 3 from section 2, but there are only 1 sections before the update'`  when I trying to (delete section zero, then insert section 2) . please help me

Comment: Sir! here is the commit change . https://github.com/nazmulkp/PagginationSwift3/commit/0ce0f8cbf91c0cfd5969d8cdd4d340021817a9f5

Comment: @NazmulHasan All deletions should be performed on zone zero. Don't forget to call `tableView.beginUpdates()` before and `tableView.endUpdates()` after performing the changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150973/discussion-between-nazmul-hasan-and-dasblinkenlight).

Comment: Sir I did `tableView.beginUpdates(`) before and `tableView.endUpdates()` but it is not working for me

Comment: sir please help me i unable to figure out how to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

Use
`students.removeFirst()`for removing the first element and
`students.removeLast()` for removing the last element.

If you want to remove it at a certain index use,
`students.remove(at: theindexyouwant)`

### **EDIT:**

If you want animation during the delete use:
`tableview.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(tRemove, withRowAnimation: .Left)`

Comment: tableview not update smoothly when I remove item using `self.students.removeFirst()`

Comment: `tableview.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` should not work because it is 2D array