# Swift UIbutton is clicked add a string and when clicked again it removes it

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm a beginner in swift, I'm making an app in storyboard UIKit, and I need some help basically I need to set up a view controller that has buttons on it that when clicked add a string on the bottom of the VC, and if clicked again it will remove that same string. On the VC there going to be multiple buttons like this for options also on the bottom of the VC I need the label to update during the app also it should display like this for example. "Football","Basketball","Golf". It needs to be displayed just like that on the bottom with quotes and commas. I've to turn to make action buttons with a global array and put that inside each button but I can't figure out how to remove it when the button clicked again, also if you click the button again it'll add the same thing again so in the array you'll have two of the same strings. Anything would help.

P.S I need to do this in UIkit and Storyboard

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24051661/10279508

Answer (score 0):

You can make list of outlets to an array UIButton, handle list of actions when click into UIButton with a function. Using 'isSelected' property of UIButton to distinguish 'delete' or not.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var allButtons: [UIButton]!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    
    @IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        sender.isSelected.toggle()
        _updateDescription()
    }
    
    private
    func _updateDescription() {
        descriptionLabel.text = allButtons
                                    .filter { $0.isSelected }
                                    .compactMap { $0.titleLabel?.text }
                                    .map { "\"\($0)\"" }
                                    .joined(separator: ", ")
    }
}
```