# How do I implement Swift's Comparable protocol?

Tags: compare, protocols, swift

How do I use the Comparable protocol in Swift? In the declaration it says I'd have to implement the three operations <, <= and >=. I put all those in the class but it doesn't work. Also do I need to have all three of them? Because it should be possible to deduce all of them from a single one.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The Comparable protocol extends the Equatable protocol -> implement both of them

In [Apple's Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Comparable_Protocol/index.html) is an example  from Apple (within the Comparable protocol reference) you can see how you should do it: Don't put the operation implementations within the class, but rather on the outside/global scope. Also you only have to implement the `<` operator from `Comparable` protocol and `==` from `Equatable` protocol.

Correct example:

```
class Person : Comparable {
    let name : String

    init(name : String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

func < (lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
    return lhs.name < rhs.name
}

func == (lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
    return lhs.name == rhs.name
}

let paul = Person(name: "Paul")
let otherPaul = Person(name: "Paul")
let ben = Person(name: "Ben")

paul > otherPaul  // false
paul <= ben       // false
paul == otherPaul // true
```

Comment: How do I do this in playground?

Comment: I don't get how this is considered 'implemented' when the actual code isn't in the class at all... Shouldn't the == < and all the rest be inside the class? Yet when I try that I get errors.. Do you know what I'm failing to understand?

Comment: @fjlksahfob the reason is because it's adding an extension to the operator at a scope outside the class. You could even do something like `func == (lhs: ClassA, rhs: ClassB) -> Bool` if you wanted, to compare two different classes (from testing it appears to only work in the direction specified, so you would also have to create `func == (lhs: ClassB, rhs: ClassA) -> Bool`). In other words, the Swift compiler interprets `(X == Y)` as `==(X, Y)` and not `X.==(Y)`

Comment: When you ctrl-click `Comparable` the definition tells you need to implement `==`,  `>=` and `>` which leads to a compile time error. I guess this is a documentation error from Apple? Your way works. I submitted a bug report.

Comment: Finally the first language that provides a Comparable interface with operator overloading. It's annoying to have both operator overloading and CompareTo methods in C# and have to use the pesky CompareTo all the time.

Comment: @paulpaul1076 Swift isn't the first one for sure, Haskell for example, which has also influenced Swift a lot. I get your point though, it's really nice to have custom operator overloading :D

Comment: @Kametrixom, oh, cool, I haven't used Haskell, so I don't know, thanks for enlightening me. And C# does have custom operator overloading, but for sorting you use the IComparable interface, and compare by doing a.CompareTo(b) < 0, which means a < b. Why not just Make IComparable have the < operator instead? That was my point. Swift looks nice.

Comment: In Swift 5, I found that I didn't need to conform to equatable or implement `==` when conforming to Comparable. I implemented only `<`, and was still able to test for equality. Is it just being clever about re-using `<` with swapped arguments?

Comment: What if we do not implement == from Equatable protocol? In the documentation, Apple says that we need to conform to the Equatable protocol and Comparable protocol, but when I test in the playground without Equatable I can test >= operator ?!

Answer (score 7):

Here is an update of Kametrixom's answer for **Swift 3**:

```
class Person : Comparable {

    let name : String

    init(name : String) {
        self.name = name
    }    

    static func < (lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name < rhs.name
    }

    static func == (lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name
    }
}
```

Instances of the `Person` class can then be compared with the relational operators as follows:

```
let paul = Person(name: "Paul")
let otherPaul = Person(name: "Paul")
let ben = Person(name: "Ben")

print(paul > otherPaul)  // false
print(paul <= ben)       // false
print(paul == otherPaul) // true
```

Answer (score 0):

To implement Swift's `Comparable` protocol, you need to conform to the `Equatable` protocol first by implementing `static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool`, then implementing the only required function `static func < (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool` for `Comparable`.

Instead of declaring global operator overloads, you should instead implement the protocol conforming methods within the struct/class itself. Although global operator overloads satisfy the protocol conformance, it's bad practice to declare them that way instead of the intended static methods on the struct/class.

If you look at the documentation example, you will see that the same is shown as sample code.

I would instead write the following:

```
class Person: Comparable {
    let name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    static func < (lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name < rhs.name
    }

    static func == (lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name
    }
}
```

or even separate out the protocol conformance out of the class declaration like so:

```
class Person {
    let name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

extension Person: Comparable {
    static func < (lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name < rhs.name
    }

    static func == (lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name
    }
}
```

which would probably be closer to production level code.